# EMR cluster automatically terminating after few days

Tags: pyspark, amazon-emr, amazon-kinesis

I've a AWS EMR cluster executing a spark streaming job. It takes streaming data from Kinesis stream and process it. It works fine for few days but after 12-15 days the cluster terminates automatically. I checked in events tab, it shows
**cluster has terminated with errors with a reason of STEP_FAILURE.**

Anyone has any idea why step failure can occur when the step successfully ran for few days ?

Comment: Please check the log in the `Log files` column under the steps tab. Check stderr and stdout to find why the step has failed. It should help you to understand why the step has failed. Steps can fail at any time if something has gone wrong. The reason for failure you will be able to find in the logs.

Comment: Thank you, I checked the log files and got the reason for step failure.

Comment: Cool. That's Nice. Happy Learning :)

Answer (score 1):

Go to the EMR console, and check the step option. If it is set as follows:

[image]

```
Action on failure:Terminate cluster
```

then the cluster will be terminated when the step failed.

Comment: Yes it says step failure.
But how can a step fails if it was working properly for few days ?

Comment: Check your log and find the reason. Whatever it could occur and you should catch the exception.

Comment: Thank you, I checked the logs and got the reason for step failure.